# Why can the union of events be expressed as additions of those events?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

To illustrate let's say that E, F, and G are three events. Then we're asked to find expressions for the events that of E, F, G at most one of them occurs.

My answer to this is: 
$$ E^{c}F^{c}G^{c}\cup E^{}F^{c}G^{c}\cup E^{c}F^{}G^{c}\cup E^{c}F^{c}G^{} $$

the answer in my book is:

$$ E^{c}F^{c}G^{c} + E^{}F^{c}G^{c} + E^{c}F^{}G^{c} + E^{c}F^{c}G^{} $$

My question is what's the difference between the expressions and if they are equivalent.

Comment: What book are you using, and how does it describe the $+$ sign in this context?

Answer (score 1):

Speculating, I'd say $+$ for events means mutually exclusive union (so disjoint union), so we add their probabilities. So it's really the same but stated so that we can apply the sum axiom for their probabilities.